# angular.js TypeError: b.empty is not a function UI.grid

Tags: angularjs

```
    vm.getAllLeave = function () {
        leavetypeservice.getAllLeave()
        .success(function (leaveTypeView) {
            debugger;

            vm.gridOptions.data = leaveTypeView;
            //vm.leaveTypeView = leaveTypeView;
        })
    };

    vm.gridOptions = {
        columnDefs: [
            { field: 'name', name: 'Name' }, { field: 'applicableForName', name: 'Applicable For' }]
    };

    vm.getAllLeave();
}

leavetypecontroller.$inject = ["leavetypeservice", "$location", "$http"];
angular.module('myapp').controller('leavetypecontroller', leavetypecontroller)
```

Comment: angular.js:9037 TypeError: b.empty is not a function
    at ui-grid.min.js:6
    at angular.js:5420
    at ui-grid.min.js:6
    at C (angular.js:10549)
    at angular.js:10635
    at g.$eval (angular.js:11528)
    at g.$digest (angular.js:11373)
    at g.$apply (angular.js:11634)
    at g (angular.js:7635)
    at I (angular.js:7801)

Comment: <div id="grid1" ui-grid="vm.gridOptions" class="grid">

</div>

Answer (score 0):

leaveTypeView is the response. To get the data (assuming JSON) you need vm.gridOptions.data = leaveTypeView.data

The error you're getting is UI grid attempting to parse a non JSON element.

Comment: angular.js:9037 TypeError: b.empty is not a function
    at ui-grid.min.js:6
    at angular.js:5420
    at ui-grid.min.js:6
    at C (angular.js:10549)
    at angular.js:10635
    at g.$eval (angular.js:11528)
    at g.$digest (angular.js:11373)
    at g.$apply (angular.js:11634)
    at g (angular.js:7635)
    at I (angular.js:7801)